# Which is more efficient Object class casting or Double.parseDouble(String)

Tags: java

A block of code similar to this sparked some debate on to which part of the code was most efficient or if there was a more correct way to do this.  One argument was that the cast was more efficient than creating a string to parse.  One argument was that the multiple class casts was creating more objects than creating the string to parse.

What is the "best practice"?

```
Object some_num_obj;
double some_num;
if(some_num_obj instanceof Integer)
{
    some_num = (double) (int) (Integer) some_num_obj;
}
else if(some_num_obj instanceof Double)
{
    some_num = (Double) some_num_obj;
}
else
{
     some_num = Double.parseDouble(some_num_obj.toString());
}
```

Comment: To clarify, the "Object some_num_obj" is a non-null Integer or Double but the api that returns this value returns an Object. It is possible that this code may be run thousands of times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most efficient and possibly the fastest is to use Number.doubleValue and Double.parseDouble

```
if(some_num_obj instanceof Number)
    some_num = ((Number) some_num_obj).doubleValue();
else
    some_name = Double.parseDouble(some_num_obj.toString());
```

Comment: why not casting? Autobox + memory allocation cast?;o (instead of parsing)

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is the one that is the most readable. Unless that piece of code is ran tens of thousands of times in a row, the efficiency difference is as good as non-existing.

Not really sure whether it's applicable in your application, you might want to take a look at the `java.lang.Number` class as a method parameter.

Answer (score 2):

> One argument was that the multiple class casts was creating more
>   objects

Wrong. Class casts don't create *any* objects.

Answer (score 1):

Types are nothing more than a way of telling the compiler what to do with a variable, they do not create new objects.  Both creating a string from a number and parsing the string back into a number are quite expensive.  The only potential trouble with casting is type-safety, which you take care of with the instanceof.

As a sidenote, the extra cast to double in the first part is extraneous.